# Varargs not working in 64bit with managed objects?

Tags: 64-bit, managed-c++, variadic-functions

I'm trying to migrate some managed c++ code to 64bits.
I have a function that gets varargs, and when I pass a System::String variable to it, it appears not to pass correctly.
Here is a simplification of the code that shows the problem:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>
    void test(char* formatPtr, ...)
    {
        va_list args;
        int bufSize;
        char buffer[2600];

        /////////////////////////////////////
        //parse arguments from function stack
        /////////////////////////////////////
        va_start(args, formatPtr);

        bufSize = vsprintf(buffer, (const char*) formatPtr, args);
        printf(buffer);

        va_end(args); 
    }

    void main() {
        System::String^ s;
        s = "Shahar";
        test("Hello %s", s);
        getchar();
    }
```

When this code runs in 32 bits, it displays Hello Shahar.

When it runs in 64 bits, it displays Hello Çz∟⌠■.

Assuming I want to make the least amount of changes to the code, how should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the problem is in the mix between managed code and varargs. It appears that they are [not compatible with each other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712815.aspx).

I don't know why this works in 32-bits, but it looks like the wrong thing to do.

I changed the code, so as to be only managed code, with no varargs.

Answer (score 0):

The %s specifier expects a C-style null-terminated string, not a System::String^. C++/CLI headers provide some methods that can convert System::String^ to std::string, which can be converted to a C-string, and can probably just convert straight to a C-string.

You have other problems too. void main()? Assigning a literal to a char*? Fixed-size buffer?

Comment: The %s specifier accepts System::String^ just fine. If I don't go through varargs, this works perfectly.
This is just a simplification of the code, to show the problem. I'm not interested in making this code nice. I want it to work, so I can take the solution to the 'real' code.